# Div container wont disapperar. Why is the conditional rendering not workin?

Tags: vue.js, conditional-rendering

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Intro Into Vue3</title>
  <style>
    .box {
      background-color: purple;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    {{greeting}}
    <input v-model="greeting" />
  </div>

  <hr />
  <div class="box" v-if="isVisible"></div>
  <hr>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
  <script>
    let app = Vue.createApp({
      data: function () {
        return {
          greeting: "Hello Vude3",
          isVisible: false,
        };
      },
    });
    app.mount("#app");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am working on the tutorial of freecodecamp on yt regarding vu3
at the beginning conditional rendering is explained
in the data properties there is an variable "isVisible" set to false
the v-if is not working on the purple box though its set to false

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
<div id="app">
    {{greeting}}
    <input v-model="greeting" />
</div>
```

Since you mount vue on the app, id `app.mount("#app");`, Vue.js will only control the components within the div that declares this id, and your box-class div isn't within this div and so is not controlled by vue.

so change:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Intro Into Vue3</title>
  <style>
    .box {
      background-color: purple;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    {{greeting}}
    <input v-model="greeting" />
  <hr />
  <div class="box" v-if="isVisible"></div>
  <hr>
  </div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
  <script>
    let app = Vue.createApp({
      data: function () {
        return {
          greeting: "Hello Vude3",
          isVisible: true,
        };
      },
    });
    app.mount("#app");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

to

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Intro Into Vue3</title>
  <style>
    .box {
      background-color: purple;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    {{greeting}}
    <input v-model="greeting" />
  <hr />
  <div class="box" v-if="isVisible"></div>
  <hr>
  </div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
  <script>
    let app = Vue.createApp({
      data: function () {
        return {
          greeting: "Hello Vude3",
          isVisible: true,
        };
      },
    });
    app.mount("#app");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and it will work